# How can one update the secondary Y-axis of a Plotly chart through an update menu

Tags: python, plotly

I'm looking for what the keyword is to update the secondary axis label in a Plotly chart using buttons and an updatemenu.  Everything else is working like I want.  The button setup code is below.  The goal is to change the left and right y variables the using information from the DataFrame.  The data, primary axis and both legend names changed as desired but I can't find an option to replace my made up `'secondary_axis'` keyword when making the right buttons.

```
# above here make subplots, add traces, etc.
left_buttons = []

for option in axis_options:
    left_buttons.append({'method': 'update',
                         'label': option,
                         'args': [{'y': [df[option]], 'name': [option]}, {'yaxis': {'title': option}}, [0]]})

right_buttons = []
for option in axis_options:
    right_buttons.append({'method': 'update',
                          'label': option,
                          'args': [{'y': [df[option]], 'name': [option]}, {'secondary_yaxis': {'title': option}}, [1]]})

# figure.update_layout(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually, I'm assuming that the `2` suffix goes with the trace number but I couldn't confirm that with any documentation yet.  I needed to add the overlaying and side parameters to get it where I wanted it to go.  Got some weird overlaps and missing data otherwise.

```
# above here make subplots, add traces, etc.
left_buttons = []

for option in axis_options:
    left_buttons.append({'method': 'update',
                         'label': option,
                         'args': [{'y': [df[option]], 
                                   'name': [option]}, 
                                  {'yaxis': {'title': option}}, 
                                  [0]]
                         })

right_buttons = []
for option in axis_options:
    right_buttons.append({'method': 'update',
                          'label': option,
                          'args': [{'y': [df[option]], 
                                    'name': [option]}, 
                                   {'yaxis2': {'title': option, 'overlaying': 'y', 'side': 'right'}}, 
                                   [1]]
                         })

# figure.update_layout(...
```